# .htaccess mod_rewrite subdirectory same name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**1.)**

I'm trying the rewrite ***/news/*** to ***/news/news-reader/***.

I've tried this one:

```
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ news/news-reader/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Guess what the reaulting URL is?

> news-reader-reader-reader-reader-reader-reader-reader-reader-reader-reader-reader-reader-reader-reader-reader-reader-reader-reader-reader-reader-reader

So I get a rewrite error.

How can I rewrite the part "news" in the URL in a correct way?

**2.)**

How can I rewrite "news/" to "news". So it will go to the URL without the slash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following code at root `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/de/news/news-reader/

# the line above will prevent looping witch was happened in your code 

RewriteRule ^de/news/(.*)       /de/news/news-reader/$1 [L,R=301]

# the line above will redirect /de/news/page to /de/news/news-reader/page 
# so at your code you missed to put / before target url
```

Comment: Sorry this does not work. No error no redirection, nothing.

Comment: into the root .htaccess file

to be clear

I want to rewrite this:
http://www.domain.de/de/news/something

to this:
http://www.domain.de/de/news/news-reader/something

Comment: so yourwebsite.com/news/ correct ? if /news/ is sub for root it will work try to empty browser cache

Comment: NO. yourwebsite.com/de/news/something to this: yourwebsite.com/de/news/news-reader/something - i've empty browser cache

Comment: what can I do if I want the de/news/ redirects to de/news (without slash) but keeping the same rules above?